# Use of 'common' as 'likewise'

Tags: idioms

In the poem "Reflections in a Forest", Auden writes

> To move about seems underbred
>    / and common any taste for words

We can paraphrase it as "It seems rude to move and likewise to speak."

My question concerns this apparent use of ***common*** as ***likewise***.

I checked [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/common), and the closest sense I could find is:

> (3) Shared by, coming from, or done by more than one

I understand that the example comes from poetry, but my question concerns analogous uses in everyday contexts.

For example, is there a use of ***common*** on which the following are synonymous:

1. It seems rude to move, the same to shout.
2. It seems rude to move, common to shout.
3. The flower is red. The hydrant likewise.
4. The flower is red. Common the hydrant.

(1) and (3) sound fine to me but (2) and (4) sound strained. But it might just be my idiolect. What do others think? Is ***common*** regularly used this way, or is it an idiosyncratic use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the verses in question:

> Within a shadowland of trees
>   Whose lives are so uprightly led
>   In nude august communities,
>   To move about seems underbred
>
> And common any taste for words;
>   When, thoughtlessly, they took to song,
>   Whatever one may think of birds,
>   The example that they set was wrong.

To paraphrase, within the virtuous (*upright*) and distinguished (*august*) population of trees, it seems ill-mannered (*underbred*) to move and vulgar (*common*) to speak (have *any taste for words*).

Your paraphrase has misled you:  *common* is parallel to *underbred*.

Comment: You're right, I was reading "common" as anaphoric on "underbred", when in fact it's being used literally to mean "vulgar."